# awstats(awstats_buildstaticpages.pl) asks for /awstats./etc/awstats/ directory. how to get rid of it?

Tags: awstats

I'm trying to run awstats static pages building:

```
awstats_buildstaticpages.pl -config=/etc/awstats/awstats.example.com -dir=/var/www/share-new/sites-prod/example.com/generated/statistics/ -awstatsprog=/var/www/awstats/awstats.pl
```

but keep receiving error:

```
Build main page: "/var/www/awstats/awstats.pl" -config=/etc/awstats/awstats.example.com -staticlinks -output
Error: Couldn't open log file "/var/www/share-new/sites-prod/example.com/generated/statistics/awstats./etc/awstats/awstats.example.com.html" for writing : No such file or directory.
```

why is it looking for that weird `awstats./etc/awstats/` directory? How I can get rid of it and let it save html output directly to /var/www/share-new/sites-prod/example.com/generated/statistics/?

Comment: Carefully review your configuration, there might be a typo somewhere.

Comment: @dawud installed from yum with minimum changes

Answer (score 0):

oh! wrong was path `-config=/etc/awstats/awstats.example.com`. its looking for 
`,"${searchdir}awstats.$SiteConfig.conf"` file.

So must be `-config=example.com`